# Activities Overview showing all open applications?

Tags: gnome

I would like to know if it's possible to show my current open applications next to the activities overview at the top left corner of the screen ? Here is an image to show you what I mean :

[activities overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rcnM.jpg)

For example here only Google Chrome is showing even though I have VSCode & Terminal open in the background. I would like VSCode & Terminal to show next to Google Chrome if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "out of the box" version of GNOME is relatively pared-down, and doesn't offer what you're looking for. But there's [a large list of extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/) that extend and/or modify GNOME in many ways.

Something similar to your idea can be achieved with a "task bar" extension. Some examples of such an extension would be (arbitrarily chosen)

[RocketBar](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5180/rocketbar/)

[BaBar Task Bar](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4000/babar/)

[DashBar](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5143/dashbar/)

[Dash to Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/)

Most extensions only show icons for the running apps, not the app title. You can find those extensions and more on [extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org/).

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting very close to what I want! Unfortunately, I didn't find an extension that does exactly what I want; showing the app title instead of icons, on the top bar. I did find something similar but unfortunately it's kinda buggy and it only shows it on a bottom bar.